# Inserting data into two different table with relation using Eloquent

Tags: mysql, eloquent

I have to tables called customers and address.

Customer table

```
id
customer_name
address_id
```

address table

```
id
address
```

The form has customer name and address inputs together. I would like to insert address and get address Id and insert into customer table with address id and customer name. Is this possible?

my model looks like this

```
public function addCustomer($data)
{

    $this->table('address')->insertGetId([ 
        'address' => $data['address'],
    ]);

    $this->table('customers')->insertGetId([ 
        'customer_name' => $data['customer_name'],
        'address_id' => //how can I get address ID,
    ]);
}
```

How to get address ID from freshly inserted row?

Thanks.

Comment: `insertGetId()` returns the inserted `id`.

Comment: don't I need to use save() ?

Answer (score 0):

```
public function addCustomer($data)
{
    $address = $this->table('address')->insertGetId([ 
      'address' => $data['address'],
    ]);

    $this->table('customers')->insertGetId([ 
       'customer_name' => $data['customer_name'],
       'address_id' => $address 
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You were doing correctly. You need to initialize the **address id** variable and set it to the address_id in the insert of the customers table

```
public function addCustomer($data)
{
    // storing address_id to the $address_id variable
    $address_id = $this->table('address')->insertGetId([ 
      'address' => $data['address'],
    ]);

    $this->table('customers')->insertGetId([ 
       'customer_name' => $data['customer_name'],
       'address_id' => $address_id 
       // setting address_id from the above address id
    ]);
}
```